# Problem with Safe Navigation Operator

Tags: compile-error

I'm trying to understand and use safe navigation operator . So, this is the original line -

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = (List<Opportunity>) Database.query(query.toSOQL());
return ( oppList.isEmpty() ) ? null : oppList.get( 0 );
```

With Safe Navigation this is what i've done -

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = (List<Opportunity>) Database.query(query.toSOQL());
return oppList ?.oppList.get( 0 );
```

On trying to save I get this error - *Variable does not exist: oppList*.

Can someone help in pointing out what am I missing/what wrong i'm doing here?

-Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct *return* statement should be `return oppList?.get(0)`

As stated in the [apex dev guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm), if the left-hand-side of the chain expression evaluates to null, the right-hand-side is not evaluated. In `return oppList?.oppList.get(0)`, since the list of opportunities `oppList` is not null, the safe navigation operator is looking for `oppList` property within the list. Since, the property doesn't exist, it throws variable does not exist error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation .